# Why is HttpContext.Session status changing to disposed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to store token I get from external api on session.

code snippet concerning this;

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async void Post()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetValue<User>("Token") == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetValue("Token", "test");
                var res = await _loginBusiness.GetToken();
                HttpContext.Session.SetValue("Token", res);
            }
        }
```

> HttpContext.Session.SetValue("Token", "test");

in this part, it doesn't occur any error but second the same code line give an error after GetToken().

related error

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'IFeatureCollection has been disposed.
> Object name: 'Collection'.'

Also GetToken():

```
        public async Task<User> GetToken()
        {
            String url = "login/login";

            var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("VoiceScope");

            var postRes = await client.PostAsync<User>(new UserLogin(), url);

            return postRes;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `async void`. These promises can't be observed and their semantics end up a lot different from a normal `Task`. Your disposal is happening early because the infrastructure just assumes your `Post` method has completed (it has no way to tell otherwise).

Change the signature of `Post` to be:

```cs
public async Task Post()
```

Please note that `async void` should be limited to event handlers.

Comment: Okay, I understood why it is. However, I command `await` and I expect method waiting at there.

Comment: @ilyasvarol then no, you *don't understand* why it is. Please read up more on `async/await` and the pitfalls of `async void`

Comment: anyway thanks again! I am going to learn more information about this.

Comment: This line: _"Please note that async void should be limited to event handlers."_ saved my life! LOL Even if I already knew, the immersion in my problem totally wiped out this "little detail"! Tks, @pinkfloydx33!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about using HttpContext. You have IHttpContextAccessor in asp.net core.
I think for store token you can use this

```
public class UserContext
{
    public UserContext(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        Token = GetAccessToken(context);
    }

    private static string GetAccessToken(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)contextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity;
        return identity?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "token")?.Value;
    }


    public string Token { get; }
}
```

And then, add this staff in your DI like scope object and use it in controllers via ServiceProvider.

Comment: thanks for your effort but I just want to store token in session very simply.

Comment: I think "httpcontext" is changing after post action in the "GetToken()". If I block this, I solve my problem.

Comment: It's because you're incorrectly using async void